# ngOnInit() inside of template

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I am using the [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) Angular library to implement modal functionality in my app. I am at a point where I would like to make an HTTP request when the modal loads. The content for the modal is in the form of a template. An example from ngx-bootstrap's documentation is listed below.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>
 
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    [Would like to have results of HTTP call here]
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

What I don't know how to do is implement `ngOnInit()` functionality in this template. If it were a normal component I could make use of `ngOnInit()` inside the `compenent-name.ts` file. Where can I place the code that makes the HTTP request so I can add it to the modal content once it loads?

Comment: You do it in the actual component class (via a service, components shouldn't make HTTP calls); click the other tab in the example.

Comment: I would like to use the template example. The component version didn’t work well for me.

Comment: All of the examples on that page have both an HTML and a TS file.

Comment: Create a another component for modal and you can use it like [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component) . Also, do not forget to add your modal component inside `entryComponents` array of module if you are using Angular version older than 10. By the way, you can use `ngOnInit()` lifecycle of the modal component.

Comment: Just do the call in openModal..? Because you use a template, you stay inside your component scope so just treat it as part of your component.

Comment: @MikeOne That did the trick for me. If you write this up as an answer I will accept it. Thanks